# Is it possible to add progess bar to docker logs?

Tags: docker, logging

I am trying to view docker logs live with -f(follow) flag. Since container is busy updating(deleting, editing) database file, is it possible to show a progress bar in the log while docker is busy with database.

**Log file will show:**

> Deleting student table
>   (progress bar here) << this shows some activity for deleting student table
>   Updating file  << continues after delete function

This will show some activity is going on instead of having the feeling of being stuck at "deleting student table"

Comment: Not one that updates in place, since you're ultimately writing out to a log file, but it's possible to show incremental progress in other ways.  What have you tried so far, and what problems are you encountering?

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I am a bit clueless. Since the process of updating db won't return anything until its finished so I want to show some progress that something is going on. How can you show incremental progress ?

Comment: Printing out `10%`, `20%`, _etc._ as separate lines in the log file is common enough, but that involves your application knowing what's happening and having a guess as to how much progress is happening.